# Catch a dynamic URL from controller in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm using Symfony 4 and the way to capture a route and direct it to a method of a controller is as follows:

```
/**
 * @Route("/my/route", name="name_of_route")
 */
public function myMethod() {
    /* some logic that render a view */
}
```

Within my application, I have a shopping cart. Let's suppose a hypothetical example where I have the following nesting of categories:

```
Solid
└>sand
  └>refined sand
  └>gross sand        
...etc...
```

if the user click on refined sand, I want to generate the follow URL:

```
www.myWeb.com/solid/sand/refined-sand
```

The problem is, how do I capture this URL with annotations since it is dynamic? That is, I can not do the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{category}/{subcategory}/{product}", name="name_of_route")
 */
public function myMethod() {
    /* some logic that render a view */
}
```

Because I do not know how many nesting levels the category has.

I hope my question was understood.

Comment: Why are not you use `RouterListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a catch all route, such as:

```
public function catchAllAction($url) 
{
    // ...
}
```

You can then split the `$url` into segments on the `/` character, and match the categories against your entities as required.

```
$categories = explode('/', $url);
```

As you're using annotations for your routes, you would need to make sure this was the last route registered in your application to prevent it from mistakenly matching other routes. You can do this in the `routing.yml` config file.

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

catch_all:
    path: /{url}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Category:catchAll }
    methods: [ GET ]
    requirements:
        url: '.+'
```

If possible, I would also suggest prefixing the route to limit the route patterns it might match. E.g. `/categories/{url}`

Comment: To do this you need to take one more step. You need to allow `/` as a valid character in the route otherwise it won't match because the router will take it as a delimiter and look for a route that matches the number of arguments. There's a special doc entry about how this can be done: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Comment: @Joe, good shout. I've added a route parameter requirements to the yaml file.